# Controlling one UITable from another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am building a simple iOS app that has two `UITableViewController`s which I use to create a horizontal table for date navigation `(ScrollingDateViewController)` and a second plain `UITableView` `(LogItemsTableViewController)` for displaying logged items for the selected date.

In my `viewDidLoad` method I have the following:

```
NSLog(@"show scrolling date selector");
scrollingDateViewController=[[ScrollingDateViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScrollingDateView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
CGRect rect=CGRectMake(0,330,320,100);    
scrollingDateViewController.view.frame=rect;
scrollingDateViewController.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
scrollingDateViewController.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:scrollingDateViewController.view];

NSLog(@"show log item selector");
logItemsTableViewController=[[LogItemsTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LogItemsView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
rect=CGRectMake(0,0,320,330);    
logItemsTableViewController.view.frame=rect;
logItemsTableViewController.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:logItemsTableViewController.view];

[super viewDidLoad];
```

All appears to be working well with the two tables. The problem I have now is how do I control the log item table when a new date is selected in the scrolling date table. I suspect the answer is quite simple but I am new to iOS programming and just working my way through the issues. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: In the end Hamed pointed me in the right direction but I used a slightly different approach. I ended up placing a reference of the logItemsDateView controller in the scrollingDateViewController which works perfectly. I had to change the order in which I add the views to the main view, but thanks so much to all.

Answer (score 5):

You need to implement this function

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

for your `ScrollingDateViewController`. Now in this function you must implement your idea about changing `LogItemsTableViewController`. For doing that you must access to `UITableView` of `LogItemsTableViewController` into the `ScrollingDateViewController`.

I hope it be useful for you!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have been more specific. I get that I have to override the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. What I'm struggling with how do I get a handle on the UITableView of the LogItemsTableViewController in the ScrollingDateViewController.
Do I create a new UITableView in the ScrollingDateViewController and then how do I pass it to the LogItemsViewController?

Comment: I suggest you set your tables delegate to the parent of your controllers and now override their functions into the parent controller. Now in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you can access in two tables if you made your tables as a property or as a public function.

Comment: I thought about that, but my concern was how do I identify/differentiate which table is calling the delegate methods if both tables are using the same controller as a delegate?

Comment: In each function that is overridden you can check by this `if([aTable isEqual:tableView])... else if([bTable isEqual:tableView])...` which table is under work.

Comment: Thanks Hamed. I'll give that a go and let know how it goes.